# Django Rest Framework request as parameter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm learning Django rest Framework. I know how to use Class Based Views. Why methods GET, PUT, DELETE, ETC needs the "request" parameter even if the object itself contains the same request attribute?

For example, in this code:

```
class ArticleDetailViewAPIView(APIView):

def get_object(self, pk):
    object = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk)
    return object

def get(self, request, pk):
    object = self.get_object(pk=pk)
    serializer = SerializerArticle(object)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

For example, if in the get method I put the line:

```
print("Equal: ", self.request is request)
```

In the console, the output is TRUE

Comment: In Django, every view ***must have a required argument `request`***. In the cases of CBV, the incoming request is setting as an *instance attribute* to get a ***better `OOP` experience***

Comment: So, is only for convention purpose?